# Big table with referential integrity or field typification?

Tags: object-oriented, database, orm

I'm using an ORM (Propel) and PHP to create Objects and store them in a database. So, I'm facing a recurrent problem and I'm pretty sure this happened to someone before.

My data model looks something like this:

[image: Strategy pattern situation]

So class A needs a reference to something from the hierarchy of `Clase Parent` (abstract class), this is not the problem. The idea behind this solutions is that in the future it would be very easy to create new strategies. But remember I said I'm using an ORM to store info in the database?

Well, the database has 3 tables: `A_table`, `B_table` and `C_table`. So here comes the situation:

`A_table` needs to be related to the strategy. Whats the best way to go?

1. Create a strategy type reference table, assosiate a type to the A_table and have a relation_id thats just an intenger with a value (no referential integrity whatsoever)
2. Create one field per strategy in the A_table, and allow them to be null

Really looking forward for opinions and why its best one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem, using NHibernate as my ORM.  In that case, I created a separate table for `Parent` with just an `Id` column in it.  Then I created one-to-one relationships between `B` and `Parent` and `C` and `Parent`.  So, for every record in `B` or `C` there is a corresponding record in `Parent`.  You do this by making your primary keys in `B` and `C` also foreign keys referencing `Parent`. Then I could create a normal foreign key relationship between `A` and `Parent`.

That has 2 advantages:

1. It's easy to add new strategies
2. It's easy to add properties to the `Parent` class, if necessary

Of course, you end up with one more table, but I found that the ORM made it all transparent.